# Is there always an Adorner Layer between a parent content control and its children?

Tags: wpf, xaml, adornerlayer

Just trying to clarify an observation. (I can't seem to find a straight answer from Google). I am doing some image editing using adorners. My images are both in an `ItemsControl` and as children of an `InkCanvas`.

When using `GetAdornerLayer()` for an element within the `ItemsControl`, I automatically obtain an Adorner Layer over the element within the `ItemsTemplate`. But if I go further up the visual tree with `VisualTreeHelper`, I find another `AdornerLayer` above all the items of the `ItemsControl`. (The `ItemsControl` is itself a child of a `Grid`). On the other hand, when accessing the `AdornerLayer` for a child of the `InkCanvas`, I get an adorner layer that lies between the `InkCanvas` itself and its children.

Hence, in both cases, it seems apparent that WPF is always placing an adornerlayer between a contentcontrol and its children.

Is this indeed the case?

TIA.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on how the `ControlTemplates` of the controls are defined. The `AdornerLayer.GetAdornerLayer` method traverses up the visual tree starting at the specified `Visual` and returns the adorner layer of the first `AdornerDecorator` or `ScrollContentPresenter` element it finds.

So WPF doesn't automatically "always placing an adornerlayer between a contentcontrol and its children". It is rather the control author that provides the adorner layer by adding an [AdornerDecorator](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.documents.adornerdecorator(v=vs.110).aspx) to the visual tree.

If you for example look at the default `ControlTemplate` for the `Window`, you will see that it indeed includes an `<AdornerDecorator>` element.